# azure storage size of partition key out of range?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

according to this link , a partition key can be 1kb (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

so why do I get error "the partition key is out of range" ?

I am putting a url value like https://xxx into the partition key . Maybe the slashes are a problem?
Thanks,Peter

Answer (score 11):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/

> The following characters are not allowed in values for the PartitionKey and RowKey properties:
>
> - The forward slash (/) character
> - The backslash () character
> - The number sign (#) character
> - The question mark (?) character
> - Control characters from U+0000 to U+001F, including:
>
>   1. The horizontal tab (\t) character
>   2. The linefeed (\n) character
>   3. The carriage return (\r) character
> - Control characters from U+007F to U+009F

Comment: What is strange, though, in cosmos db: I can define a `PartitionKey` like `/foo/bar` when I use the _Data Explorer_ in portal.azure.com.  I can use the python API to display these values (using `query_entries(tablename)`, but I cannot query them by PartitionKey.